# Vite build fails, 'emitter' is imported by emitter?commonjs-external, but could not be resolved – treating it as an external dependency

Tags: vuejs3, vite, vue-composition-api

First of all link to the issue

https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-script-setup-with-vite-mx4xx2?file=package.json

To reproduce the problem run command

```
npm run build
```

Then you get error in logs

> transforming (119) node_modules/lodash/_hashDelete.js'emitter' is
> imported by emitter?commonjs-external, but could not be resolved –
> treating it as an external dependency

Trying to run npm run serve gives console error

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "emitter".
> Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

I know this error is caused by package `geostyler-sld-parser`, specificaly this line in App.vue

```
const sldParser = new SLDParser()
```

I need this package and run build/serve successfully, anyone knows how to configure vite correctly? I tried some plugins but nothing worked so far.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, so the issue was with dependency stream v0.0.2 that geostyler-sld-parser used.

To fix it I added alias for emitter so stream package resolves emitter correctly.

```
resolve: {
    alias: [
      {
        emitter: require.resolve('emitter-component'),
      },
    ]
```

Another solution that I considered is using `patch-package` module and fix dependency by hand in node modules.